# Collective book / odt template to latex

Tags: books, import, export

I have to create a collective book for a lab, humanities field, where authors don't use latex. I found some ideas to insert in a same chapter names of authors appearing in the table of contents, an abstract and multi-bibliographies, but the real difficulty seems to be the importation. I studied the possibility to give them a openoffice template, and convert their files to latex, or lyx then latex. However, when I convert chapters from tex to odt, then from odt to tex, the result is really different. And I don't speak about references or pictures management...
Do you have some ideas in order to simplify the work?

Comment: My suggestion is a workflow from simplest to complex, where all is made by the authors in the simplest possible format (i.e., Markdown) or if it can't be, first export all ODT files to Markdown or even to plain text, then build the book with bookdown,  that can be exported well to LaTeX or whatever, but as far as possible never go on the other way (i.e., from complex to  simpler) as any export  of LaTeX to any other format will be always a pain.

Comment: Great suggestion @fran . I will try to clean contributions first, before importing them in a machine more complex, latex friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is how I proceeded. I sent an odt template to the authors, and they sent me their text using it more or less. We sent comments using Libreoffice. I then used pandoc to convert the odt file to HTML, then HTML to tex (to export the images) and tex to lyx. I cleaned up the code with lyx, it didn't take much longer than that. Finally, I used the memory class and the specific codes in the preamble with the suffix to get a TOC with the author's name.
I hope this will help!